# SendFailure error when performing reserve asset transfer from rococo asset hub to parachain

Tags: parachain, xcm, rococo, assethub

I'm getting a SendFailure error(on asset hub) when performing a reserve asset transfer of ROC from rococo asset hub to a parachain, does anyone know what might be the cause? Or how can I further debug the issue?

This is the call I'm doing: `0x1f0203010100b5200300010100e266243731bf69fff27133f3cbb8def28c6fd26d688d14fee34ab6950351aa0f030400010000070010a5d4e800000000`

Update:

I've replicated the issue using chopsticks, here are the logs:

```
xcm::weight                  TRACE: WeightInfoBounds message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }, xcm: Xcm([]) }])
xcm::pallet_xcm::do_reserve_transfer_assets DEBUG: origin MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, dest MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }, beneficiary MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [226, 102, 36, 55, 49, 191, 105, 255, 242, 113, 51, 243, 203, 184, 222, 242, 140, 111, 210, 109, 104, 141, 20, 254, 227, 74, 182, 149, 3, 81, 170, 15] }) }, assets MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), fee-idx 0
xcm::contains                TRACE: ConcreteAssetFromSystem asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }
xcm::contains                TRACE: IsForeignConcreteAsset asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }
xcm::contains                TRACE: IsTrustedBridgedReserveLocationForConcreteAsset asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }, universal_source: X2(GlobalConsensus(Rococo), Parachain(1000))
xcm::contains                TRACE: IsTrustedBridgedReserveLocationForConcreteAsset origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } is not remote to the universal_source: X2(GlobalConsensus(Rococo), Parachain(1000))
xcm::contains                TRACE: IsForeignConcreteAsset asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }
xcm::contains                TRACE: ConcreteAssetFromSystem asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }
xcm::pallet_xcm::build_and_execute_xcm_transfer_type DEBUG: origin MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, dest MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }, beneficiary MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [226, 102, 36, 55, 49, 191, 105, 255, 242, 113, 51, 243, 203, 184, 222, 242, 140, 111, 210, 109, 104, 141, 20, 254, 227, 74, 182, 149, 3, 81, 170, 15] }) }, assets [MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }], transfer_type LocalReserve, fees_handling FeesHandling::Batched(MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }), weight_limit: Unlimited
xcm::weight                  TRACE: WeightInfoBounds message: Xcm([TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }])
xcm::weight                  TRACE: WeightInfoBounds message: Xcm([TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }])
xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit   TRACE: origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, message: Xcm([TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }]), weight_credit: Weight { ref_time: 294654000, proof_size: 6196 }
xcm::barriers                TRACE: TrailingSetTopicAsId origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, instructions: [TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }], max_weight: Weight { ref_time: 294654000, proof_size: 6196 }, properties: Properties { weight_credit: Weight { ref_time: 294654000, proof_size: 6196 }, message_id: None }
xcm::barriers                TRACE: TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, instructions: [TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }], max_weight: Weight { ref_time: 294654000, proof_size: 6196 }, properties: Properties { weight_credit: Weight { ref_time: 294654000, proof_size: 6196 }, message_id: None }
xcm::process                 TRACE: origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }), total_surplus/refunded: Weight { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 }/Weight { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 }, error_handler_weight: Weight { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 }
xcm::process_instruction     TRACE: === TransferAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }]), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) } }
xcm::currency_adapter        TRACE: internal_transfer_asset asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000) }, from: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Rococo), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, to: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }
xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit   TRACE: result: Ok(())
xcm::pallet_xcm::note_unknown_version TRACE: XCM version is unknown for destination: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2093)) }
runtime::system              TRACE: Used block weight: PerDispatchClass { normal: Weight { ref_time: 1833216000, proof_size: 14995 }, operational: Weight { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 }, mandatory: Weight { ref_time: 10123204000, proof_size: 14325 } }
runtime::system              TRACE: Used block length: 5669
runtime::system              TRACE: Extrinsic failed at block(3699897): <wasm:stripped>
runtime::xcmp-queue-migration DEBUG: Lazy migration finished: item gone
runtime::system              DEBUG: [3699897] 0 extrinsics, length: 5669 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 1833216000, proof_size: 14995) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 10846204000, proof_size: 83501) (0%)
```

But they don't provide much insight into the issue, the only error I can see is `Extrinsic failed at block(3699897): <wasm:stripped>`

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with XCM that has a fix but still has to get to the rococo runtime, only reserve asset transfers are affected.

The issue in GitHub is https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/3070 and a patch will be [released to Kusama](https://kusama.subsquare.io/referenda/339)

Comment: Thanks! Is the issue also on Polkadot? Is there an ETA for the fix? Do you have the link to the issue?

Comment: Updated the answer to add links to the issue

Comment: Thanks Francisco!

Comment: Is there a way to know when this fix will be implemented in rococo?

Comment: It seems that the problem we are having is not related to the mentioned issue, as supposedly the issue is fixed in rococo, but we are still having the same problem